# Continue to get info from scanner in catch block

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm simply want to get a valid `int` value for `age`

But when user enters an string, why i cant get an int again?

Here is my code:

```
public static void getAge() throws InputMismatchException {

    System.out.print("Enter Your age: ");
    try {
        age = in.nextInt();
    } catch (InputMismatchException imme) {
        System.out.println("enter correct value for age:");
        in.nextInt(); // why this not works?
    }
}

Enter Your age: hh
enter correct value for age:
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
```

I want to request to enter a valid int value until a valid input enters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `nextInt()` fails to parse the input as an int, it leaves the input in the buffer. So the next time you call `nextInt()` it is trying to read the same garbage value again. You must call `nextLine()` to eat the garbage input before trying again:

```
System.out.print("Enter your age:");
try {
    age = in.nextInt();
} catch (InputMismatchException imme) {
    System.out.println("Enter correct value for age:");
    in.nextLine(); // get garbage input and discard it
    age = in.nextInt(); // now you can read fresh input
}
```

You probably want to arrange this in a loop too, so that it will keep asking repeatedly so long as the input is unsuitable:

```
System.out.print("Enter your age:");
for (;;) {
    try {
        age = in.nextInt();
        break;
    } catch (InputMismatchException imme) {}
    in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter correct value for age:");
}
```